# ¿Como limpiar el contendio un DataGrid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, datagrid

Tengo en una ventana **(WPF)** y codigo **C#** que contiene lo siguiente
un boton:

```
<Button x:Name="btnBuscar" Content="Buscar por" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="30" Click="btnBuscar_Click"/>
```

un comboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Nombre"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Apellido paterno"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Puesto"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

un Texbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbBusqueda" Height="30" Margin="0,10,160,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ingrese texto" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="230" GotFocus="tbBusqueda_GotFocus"/>
```

un DataGrid algo similar a lo siguiente (mas columnas):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUsuarios" CanUserAddRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" Margin="10,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="742" KeyUp="dataGridUsuarios_KeyUp" MouseLeftButtonUp="dataGridUsuarios_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=idUsuario}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"  Header="idUsuario" HeaderStringFormat="idUsuario" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Nombre}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Nombre"  HeaderStringFormat="Nombre" Width="105"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ApellidoP}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Apellido Paterno" HeaderStringFormat="ApellidoP" Width="105"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ApellidoM}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Apellido materno" HeaderStringFormat="ApellidoM" Width="105"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sexo}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Sexo" HeaderStringFormat="Sexo" Width="105"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

El DataGrid se llena al iniciar con los registro de una base de datos con el siguiente metodo

```
public void llenadoDataGrid()
    {
        String consulta = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP ,ApellidoM ,Sexo,Telefono,Edad,Puesto,NombreUsuario,Contraseña from usuarios;";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, new BaseDeDatos().obtenerConexion());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTableCollection collection = ds.Tables;
        DataTable table = collection[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var data = new PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid {idUsuario = row["idUsuario"].ToString(), Nombre = row["Nombre"].ToString(),
                ApellidoP = row["ApellidoP"].ToString(), ApellidoM = row["ApellidoM"].ToString(),
                Sexo = row["Sexo"].ToString()
            };
            dataGridUsuarios.Items.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

utilizo la siguiente clase que me aconsejaron para poder llenar el data grid con el metodo anterior

```
class PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid
{
    public String idUsuario { get; set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public String ApellidoP { get; set; }
    public String ApellidoM { get; set; }
    public String Sexo { get; set; }
}
```

al momento de dar en el boton buscar realizo lo siguiente

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String dato = tbBusqueda.Text;
        int index = cmbBuscarPor.SelectedIndex;
        if (dato != ""  && dato != "Ingrese texto" && index != -1)
        {
            dataGridBuscador(index, dato);
        }
        else
        {
            if (index == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("seleccione una opcion de busqueda");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un texto para la busqueda");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("busqueda valor index "+index);
    }
```

la busqueda se realiza con el metodo **dataGridBuscador** en el cual mando el index para usar cada una de las busquedas diferentes
y el problema radica a qui ya que al ejecutar esto realiza la busqueda y lo muestra en el **dataGridUsuarios** me pone una nueva fila segida de las anteriores en lugar de solo mostrar la fila o filas de la busqueda

```
        private void llenadoConBusqueda(int opcion,String dato)
    {
        String prueba = "";
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 0:
                prueba = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP ,ApellidoM ,Sexo from usuarios where Nombre ='"+dato+"';";
                break;
            case 1:
                prueba = "select idUsuario,Nombre,ApellidoP ,ApellidoM ,Sexo from usuarios where ApellidoP ='" + dato + "';";
                break;
        }
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(prueba, new BaseDeDatos().obtenerConexion());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTableCollection collection = ds.Tables;
        DataTable table = collection[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var data = new PruebaDeLLenadoDataGrid
            {
                idUsuario = row["idUsuario"].ToString(),
                Nombre = row["Nombre"].ToString(),
                ApellidoP = row["ApellidoP"].ToString(),
                ApellidoM = row["ApellidoM"].ToString(),
                Sexo = row["Sexo"].ToString()
            };
            dataGridUsuarios.Items.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Recuerdo que una vez hice algo parecido, me parece que para el datagridview había que hacer `DatagridView.Clear();`  y después `DatagridView.Refresh();` ¿Has probado algo parecido?. Otra alternativa es instanciar de nuevo el objeto, de esta forma estaría vacío.

Comment: No es un DataGridView encontré muchos ejemplos con el pero no es lo mismo para un DataGrid ya que uso ventana **(WPF)**

Comment: ¿Y si instancias de nuevo las variables? Es lo único que se me ocurre ahora mismo, de todas formas, te invito a crear un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que alguien pueda probarlo en su equipo y te puedan ayudar más fácilmente.

Comment: Podría simplificarlo lo mas que pueda para editar la pregunta y poner todo lo necesario para que lo puedan probar

Comment: Es aconsejable, una vez me dijeron "si quieres que hagan tu trabajo, que menos que facilitarlo?" así la gente podrá probar cosas y decirte si les funciona algo.

Comment: Prueba `dataGridUsuarios.Items.Clear();`

Comment: Perfecto.. con eso lo e solucionado solo  lo agrege antes de mandar a llamar al metodo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todo depende de como estés rellenando los datos en el `DataGrid`. Si, como es tu caso, usas:

```
dataGrid.Items.Add(someObject);
```

Para limpiarlo puedes usa el método `Clear` de `Items`:

```
dataGridUsuarios.Items.Clear();
```

Si usas databinding añadiendo los datos en `ItemsSource`:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = colleccion;
```

lo que debes hace es poner `ItemsSource` a `null`.

Comment: Otra forma de limpiar el dataGrid cuando se hace DataBinding a una coleccción es limpiar la colección misma en vez de setear el itemSource a null.